# systemd-nspawn transfer files to container centos

Tags: linux, centos

I try to open new container using systemd-nspawn on centos machine
the dir has a few sub-direcories, as i can see when i use ls

```
 ls ~/stage
```

> bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root 
>   run  sbin  sys  tmp  usr  var

than i enter the container, and it looks fine:

```
sudo systemd-nspawn -D ~/stage
```

> Spawning container stage on ~/stage.

but in the container:

```
stage ~ # ls -a
```

> .  ..  .bash_history  .keep

gives the results above.
how can i have the files in the container?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your prompt inside the container:

```
stage ~ #
```

That `~` means that you are in `root`'s home directory, which is `/root`.  You can run `pwd` to verify that.

Run `cd /`, and then `ls`, and you'll see what you expect to see.